# getting a blank cmd window by running command line from C#

Tags: c#, cmd

I am trying to open command line in the c folder, from C#.

the expectation is to see this in the command line window:

C:>

but instead i am getting a blank cmd window.

this is the code:

```
var startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
{
    WorkingDirectory = @"c:\",
    WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Normal,
    FileName = "cmd.exe",
    RedirectStandardInput = true,
    UseShellExecute = false
 };
 Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Why you need `RedirectStandardInput`? Without using that all is Fine with `Process.Start(startInfo)`.

Comment: You are right. but aslo Process.Start(startInfo) gives a blank cmd window.

Answer (score 2):

[`WaitForExit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb4aw7b8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is what you are looking for.

EDIT:

```
var startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
{
    WorkingDirectory = @"c:\",
    WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Normal,
    FileName = "cmd.exe",
    RedirectStandardInput = true,
    UseShellExecute = false
 };
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo = startInfo;
p.Start();
p.WaitForExit();
```

This will halt the execution of all statements after `WaitForExit`. The time you close the command window, the statements following `WaitForExit` will be executed.

Comment: Wen i add WaitForExit, i get the error message: System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo does not contain a defenition for 'WaitForExit'

Comment: Have you modified the code, based on the example code I have?

Comment: Hm, this gets me a dead cmd window saying 3 times: Invalid Handle.

Answer (score 0):

i think you're looking for this
first we'll create a process for CMD.exe and then passes "/K cd \". "/K" will "CMD.exe" to receive parameter and stay open, while "cd \" will take us to "C:/" which is your requirement

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", "/K \"cd /\"");
Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe if you use the /K Argument when executing the command, you should have a command prompt running at C:\

```
        ProcessStartInfo startinfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
        startinfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        startinfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\";
        startinfo.Arguments = "/K";
        startinfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        Process.Start(startinfo);
```

Or

```
        Process command = new Process();
        command.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        command.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\";
        command.StartInfo.Arguments = "/K";
        command.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        command.Start();
```

The /K argument executes the cmd.exe command and keeps the window open :)